# "Unable to save item 'XXX' to TCM. The process will be aborted. " in Content Porter

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, content-porter-2013

I'm getting "Unable to save item 'XXX' to TCM. The process will be aborted. " in Content Porter when I try & import a component.  The catch is that other components using the same schema import fine, but a couple generat this error. Any ideas?

The stack trace in the CP import log is below.  This is 2013 SP1

2014/09/05 11:20:16 <197> [Error] Tridion.ContentManager.InvalidXmlException: Unable to find uuid:XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX:Metadata.
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.AssertValidRootContentElement(XmlElement rootElement, XmlSchemaSet schemaSet, XmlQualifiedName expectedRootElementName)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component.AssertValidRootContentElements(XmlSchemaSet xmlSchemaSet, String rootElementName, String rootTargetNamespace)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.ValidateXml(Schema schema, XmlElement content, Repository repository)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.ValidateXml()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component.ValidateXml()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean checkInAfterSave)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__1(Boolean isRetry)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.AbortErrorHandler.Invoke[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical, UserReply additionalUserReplyOptions)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.InvokeInErrorHandler[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportAction.SaveItem(IdentifiableObject item, IdentifiableObjectData deltaObject)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.CreateImportAction.Perform(IdentifiableObjectData itemData)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItems(IList`1 items, Boolean specialGroupImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.Import(String packageName)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the key error in this stack is

> Unable to find uuid:XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX:Metadata

It looks like your component(s) either have metadata that doesn't exist in the schema anymore, or don't have mandatory metadata that exists in the schema.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to resolve this by opening the components on the source CM and saving.  I think what happened is that the ones with  the issue were created before we added metadata to the schema.

Comment: If the metadata did not have mandatory fields, I think the option in Content Porter to "Synchronize Content with Schema" would have fixed this.